# Make use of java poker-eval library

Tags: java, compilation, javac, poker

I want to make use of the poker-eval library. I heard that it's very used in C. In this [link](https://github.com/v2k/poker-eval).

i see that it has a java folder. Is it possible for me write a Java program that uses this library? How would i go about doing that?

I tried to go to `java/org/pokersource/` and run the `.java` files with `javac` but with every one of them i get errors saying

> error: cannot find symbol

What's wrong?

Comment: What specific errors? Did you follow the instructions [in the readme](https://github.com/v2k/poker-eval/blob/master/WHATS-HERE.Java) to compile the Java layer?

Comment: You might also take a look at my ojcardlib.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably help if you would give the exact commands you issue and the exact errors you get, especially what is not found.

But I guess you just did not add the dependencies to the classpath. Maybe you should read the readme of the repo? https://github.com/v2k/poker-eval/blob/master/WHATS-HERE.Java

Comment: I added the last 3 to the CLASSPATH where can i find java/pokersource.jar?

Comment: I guess that is what the build produces. There is a makefile, that is similar to Gradle / Ant / Maven, just mainly for C programs.